# Decoding Percent-Encoded String in Swift 4.2?

Tags: cocoa, swift4.2

I'm trying to decode a percent-encoded string but can't figure out how to. For example:

```
let str = "Hello%20World"

// I want to decode 'str' to 'Hello World'
```

Does anyone know the best way to do this in Swift 4.2? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove percent encoding, I would call the `removingPercentEncoding` method.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1409569-removingpercentencoding